# ibase_connect: remote computer host and shared db file from windows

Tags: php, path, firebird

Linux red hat, connect the drive to a remote server (192.168.0.103) via mount to /mnt/databases
Then trying to connect

```
$idbh = ibase_connect("192.168.0.103/3050:/mnt/databases/XXX.IB", "SYSDBA", "masterkey", "WIN1251") or die(ibase_errmsg().' on line: '.__LINE__);
```

Result

```
 ibase_connect(): I/O error for file "/mnt/databases/XXX.IB" Error while trying to open file unknown Win32 error 3
```

Try stat /mnt/databases/XXX.IB

```
  File: `/mnt/databases/XXX.IB'
  Size: 46415872        Blocks: 90752      IO Block: 16384  regular file
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 1970324836974627  Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-07-16 16:04:08.470709400 +0400
Modify: 2013-06-17 13:03:03.600143300 +0400
Change: 2013-06-17 13:03:03.600143300 +0400
```

Why i cant connect?

Comment: Is `/mnt/databases` a mount of a remote (from the perspective of the server) network location? The `Win32 error` in the message seems to suggest it is.

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to access a Firebird or Interbase database via any form of mount. The server process should be on the same machine as the disk containing the database.

Your client would then communicate with the server process to interact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the alias of the database for connections, or the full path on disk relative to the Firebird Server. http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg2-databases.html

So if on the Firebird server the database is on C:\databases\db.fdb you need to provide that.  A network drive/share is not going to work because from the FB Server context that doesnt exist.

Some applications (QuickBooks) fool you into thinking you need to share the folder where the file resides, but its actually just bootstrapping a TCP/IP socket connection to the Database Service.  Firebird does not work that way.